# Android - How Capture image from camera or add from Library

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-button, android-camera-intent

I'm new to Android development.

I have an application that allows the user to select images. I'm using an Button. When the user clicks on the Button, I'd like to allow them the option to a)select the image from the gallery, or b)use the camera to capture an image.
Please help me by suggestion or any article.

thanx

Comment: use custom dialog to show the buttons, on click the button will perform the action. it is just an idea because your question is huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read following article which explains how to capture image from Camera:
   [Capture camera image from your app](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/)

For getting images from gallery, you have to use different intent action defined in Media class.